# 'devise' gem - permission denied @rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, permission-denied

I have installed 'devise' gem.

When I tried to run

```
rails g devise User
```

I get the following error.

```
/home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:101:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/cbls-2/academics/assistant/config/routes.rb (Errno::EACCES)
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:101:in `open'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:101:in `replace!'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:59:in `invoke!'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:30:in `insert_into_file'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb:224:in `block in route'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:194:in `block in in_root'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:184:in `block in inside'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:128:in `chdir'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:128:in `cd'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:184:in `inside'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:194:in `in_root'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb:223:in `route'
from /home/cbls-2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.1.0/lib/generators/devise/devise_generator.rb:22:in `add_devise_routes'
```

I have Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.3.0

This is my gemfile

```
 gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
 gem 'mysql2'
 gem 'devise'
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
 gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

 gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
 gem 'unicorn'
 gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
      debugger console
   gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Could not run 'rails g activeadmin:resource User' also. It throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please change the permissions for the file `/home/cbls-2/academics/assistant/config/routes.rb` It will work.

Answer (score 0):

In your place i would try to change chmod for file that cause EACCESS error.
In your example it will be /home/cbls-2/academics/assistant/config/routes.rb

Comment: I tried that already sudo chown -R root /home/cbls-2/.rvm. But no help

Comment: For you i think that file cause a problem: /home/cbls-2/academics/assistant/config/routes.rb  so try to change chmod for routes.rb

Comment: Thanks...It worked for me. Please edit your answer with this. I will accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your project directory:

```
sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: how change right to the `/tmp` dir should fix the permisson of   `/home/cbls-2/academics/assistant/` ?

Comment: Throws the same error 'Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/cbls-2/academics/assistant/config/routes.rb (Errno::EACCES)
'

Comment: You needs ownership to write the re-write the pid for each server start. that's why need to change permission of /home/cbls-2/academics/assistant/tmp directory.